# decimal to octal, I can't do this code, I'm just learning to program

Tags: python

the code is, decimal to octal, you want to read a value in decimal (base 10) and convert it to OCTAL (base 8) in phyton

[my try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKMif.png)
this is my original idea for the code

```
x=int(input(" number to 1 and 10,000"))
x=0
z=0
o=""
l=x
if (l<1 and l<10000):
    prin("this number is incorrect ")
else:
      while(l<0):
         z=(l%8)
         o=(str(z))+o
         l=int(1/8)
print(" the octal is ",o)
```

Comment: No images of code. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: use the `oct()` function

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: the `else` part is executed for `l >= 1` and thus the `while l<0` loop will never be executed

Comment: `x=0` means whatever your input is, x will become 0. So your `l=x` means `l` will become 0 as well. Then `if (l<1 and l<10000):` is pretty much just like `if l<1:`, so anything greater than 1 will go into the `else` (but this part does not cause issues for calculating the octal). Technically, `0` can be converted to octal, though.
You have `while(l<0)` so if your input is greater than 0, it will skip that part entirely. `l=int(1/8)` means the `l` will be set to 0 right after. (note that you input `1` (instead of `l`) divided by 8)

Comment: And the `if` part has `if (l<1 and l<10000):`. Does anyone know a number where the value is less than 1 but not less than 10000? BTW, I don't even see a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are learning to program. So you'd better try to find the solution by yourself or else you will learn nothing from this exercise.

Yes, internet can answer your question easily, you could just ask any AI and it will answer immediatly.

To help you, I'll give a few tips:

- you're not trying to convert a decimal number to an octal number, you're trying to convert an integer number to an octal string.
- maybe try a simpler more common problem, like converting an integer to a decimal string.
- think Division and Accumulation.

### Stop reading now, and come back when you have a running solution.

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

```
num = 15
result = ""

while num > 0:
    remainder = num % 8
    num //= 8
    result = str(remainder) + result

result = "0o" + result

print(result)
```